# Crafting manual pg_depend entry

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-14

I would like to create an UNLOGGED materialized view. I seem to understand that is not possible with the current implementation of Postgresql (14).

I am investigating whether it is possible for me to do the following:

- Given that I have two tables `A` and `B`.
- Where `A` depends on `B`, so `B` would be the data source and `A` the materialized view. In my case only `A` will be UNLOGGED. `B` will be LOGGED.
- Add a new entry into the `pg_depends` catalog entry to manually specify that `A` depends on `B`, this way I retain the benefit of postgres doing the right thing for my dependencies when it comes to DROPPING the tables.

Dropping the table `B` should given an error if `A` is still present on the database, unless `ON CASCADE` is used.

I need some help with this last step as I am not familiar with the postgresql catalog and the `oid` machinery.

To keep this question practical I will be attaching a schema of my views:

```sql
CREATE UNLOGGED TABLE A(a int, b int);
CREATE TABLE B(a int, c int);
```

As a final note I understand that messing with the postgresql catalog in the above way is not advised.

Comment: What kind of dependency do you want? Should dropping B cause an error or drop A automatically? I recommend *not* to modify catalog tables.

Comment: I updated the above. This is the relevant bit:

Dropping the table `B` should given an error if `A` is still present on the database, unless `ON CASCADE` is used.

Let's say that this question is more for a theoretical sake and to familiarise with pgsql catalogs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That entry would look as follows:

```
INSERT INTO pg_depend (classid, objid, objsubid, refclassid, refobjid, refobjsubid, deptype)
VALUES (
   'pg_class'::regclass,
   'a'::regclass,
   0,
   'pg_class'::regclass,
   'b'::regclass,
   0,
   'n'  -- "normal" dependency
);
```

You can find `pg_depend` described in [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-depend.html).